# Webdesign project not seen in ToolTwist Designer

Tags: tooltwist

I created a new webdesign project, and restarted the Designer, but it does not show when I try to change the web design project. I've checked it contains all the normal directories and files (navpoints, widgets, project.xml, properties.xml, etc). The log file says it's loaded, but when I click on the project name in the designer to change web design project, I see all the other projects but not this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a extension project (under the *devel* directory) and a web design project (under the *devel/webdesign* directory, and they have the same name, the web design project will not be visible.

A common convention to prevent this is to append the suffix "_t" to the extension project name. For example, you might have the following directory locations:

> devel/myproject_t
>   devel/webdesign/myproject

Keep in mind that these are independent of any github names used for these projects, which could follow this convention, but more commonly follow the convention of a "_webdesign" suffix for the web design project, but no suffix for the extension project.